# Wordpress Your session has expired

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

In Wordpress wp-admin popup appears with message on:

**"your session has expired. Please log in to continue where you left off."**

Its happens when /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php trigger and response 
contains:

`{"wp-auth-check":false,"server_time":1519366070}`

After 15 to 30 seconds another call made /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and response contains:

`{"wp-auth-check":true,"server_time":1519366129}` and popup disappears automatically.

We have installed WP Multisites.

It also logout us immediately after logout after login, some time it gives us 30 to 40 seconds to work and then redirects us to login page.

Does any one have any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks something is wrong with your database. Please take your database back and try with fresh import. Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Yes, Thank you man, it was the DB issue, I had created new DB and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bought a domain with another company such as Truehost, log in to your control panel. Go to "WordPress manager by Softaculous".
You will see your account written there.
Click the drop down arrow to your right and a profile opens.
Change the url to what it was before, that is with a /wp at the end.
This worked for me and I hope it helps you too.
Please, do not delete anything in cpanel, just follow the above steps.